# asterisk cli command "channel originate" with call duration or length

Tags: command-line-interface, asterisk, phone-call, duration, freepbx

I am using asterisk (Freepbx).  I am using following command which is working fine. I can originate call from asterisk cli without any issue.

**channel originate SIP/tunk-name/1416XXXXXXX extension 701@from-internal**

call ring my phone number (1416XXXXXXX) and when I answer it connects with 701 Queue using my created trunk in freepbx.

I want to set call duration in this command so call disconnect after set time.
Thanks in advance

PS: I do not want to set time in queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want limit duration use

```
channel originate SIP/tunk-name/1416XXXXXXX Application Dial Local/701@from-internal/n,,S(duration_here)
```

See Dial command params.

Comment: Thanks for you reply!  Can you please advice how can I add DTMF and caller ID in this command.  I have tried ** channel originate SIP/tunk-name/1416XXXXXXX/,,D(wwww1) Application Dial Local/701@from-internal/n,,S(duration_here) **.  Looking forward to hear from you.  PS. how to add caller ID.  thanks

Comment: You can't. But you can use channel type Local/ and write all you need in dialplan